# How to solve "Disallowed attribute in HTML tag 'col" this in WordPress?

Tags: wordpress, plugins, amp-html

I have already checked with the amp plugins for my site but still not able to find the exact error.

> Disallowed attribute in HTML tag 'col'.

Comment: https://wordpress.org/support/topic/disallowed-i-attribute-in-amp-pages-conflict/ should point you in the right direction

Comment: You may check the [documentation](https://www.ampproject.org/docs/troubleshooting/validation_errors#disallowed-attribute) about the disallowed attributes in AMP. To check the supported attributes for each specific tag, search for HTML tag, and then `attrs` in the [AMP validator spec](https://github.com/ampproject/amphtml/blob/master/validator/validator-main.protoascii).

Answer (score 0):

Most of the time it happens due to images dimensions, like smaller image size than required etc, so you can figure out what to do with errors, either update images or remove it.

Not specifically featured images, the images we use in articles, including featured images if your theme is showing in article, you can check your amp version of post